# Issue on Pagination and System.Final exception when adding a new row

Tags: apex, visualforce

Currently i'm facing 2 issues in a single screen. Below i have given the code and also the error.

1. System.Final exception when clicking on Add Row in screen
2. Not able to navigate pagination using ApexPages.StandardSetController

[image]

**Visual Source Page**

```
<apex:page controller="ParameterController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters">

             <p>        
            <apex:panelGrid columns="7">
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="|<" action="{!first}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="<" action="{!onPreviousR}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">" action="{!onNextR}"  disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">|" action="{!last}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>

                <apex:outputText >{!(pageNumber * size)+1-size}-{!IF((pageNumber * size)>noOfRecords, noOfRecords,(pageNumber * size))} of {!noOfRecords}</apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputPanel style="color:#4AA02C;font-weight:bold">
                    <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus" startText="Please wait until Fetching..." stopText=""/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
           </apex:panelGrid>
           </p>

            <apex:pageblockSection >


            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!parametersList}" var="parameterItem" id="addParameter">
                <apex:column headerValue="Param Key1">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!parameterItem.Param_Key1__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Param Key2">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!parameterItem.Param_Key2__c}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Param Data 1">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!parameterItem.Param_Data1__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headerValue="Param Data 2">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!parameterItem.Param_Data2__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headerValue="Param Data 3">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!parameterItem.Param_Data3__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headerValue="Param Data 4">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!parameterItem.Param_Data4__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headerValue="Param Text">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!parameterItem.Param_Text__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Param Type">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!parameterItem.Param_Type__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            <br/>
            <apex:commandLink value="Add Row" action="{!addParameter}" reRender="addParameter"/>        
        </apex:pageblockSection>        
        <apex:pageblockSection columns="1" >
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
               <apex:commandButton value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>         
        </apex:pageblockSection>


         </apex:pageBlock>  

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class ParameterController extends BaseController{

     public List<Parameters__c> parametersList {get; set;}

     public ParameterController(){

       parametersList = new List<Parameters__c>();

       //String sql = 'SELECT Param_Key1__c, Param_Key2__c, Param_Data1__c, Param_Data2__c, Param_Data3__c, Param_Data4__c, Param_Text__c, Param_Type__c, Param_Type_Param_Key1_Param_Key2__c FROM Parameters__c';
       size = 25;      
       con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Param_Key1__c, Param_Key2__c, Param_Data1__c, Param_Data2__c, Param_Data3__c, Param_Data4__c, Param_Text__c, Param_Type__c, Param_Type_Param_Key1_Param_Key2__c FROM Parameters__c]));
       con.setPageSize(size);
       noOfRecords = con.getResultSize();

       parametersList  = (List<Parameters__c>)con.getRecords();

     }

     public void addParameter(){

       parametersList.add(new Parameters__c()); // Error at this line

     } 


   Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}

   Public Integer size = 5;

   public Integer getSize(){
    return size;
   }

  public void setSize(Integer size){
    this.size = size;
  }

 Public ApexPages.StandardSetController con{

     get{
        if(con == null){

        }
        return con;
    }
    set;
} 

public Boolean hasNext {
    get {
    //System.debug('nexttttt'+con.getHasNext());
        return con.getHasNext();
    }
    set;
}

public Boolean hasPrevious {
    get {
        return con.getHasPrevious();
    }
    set;
}

public Integer pageNumber {
    get {
        return con.getPageNumber();
    }
    set;
}

public void first() {
    con.first();
}

public void last() {
    con.last();
}

public void onPreviousR() {
    con.previous();
}

public void onNextR() {
    con.next();
}



}
```

**1. Indicated where the Error occurs in controller, which given as a comment in above code**

Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

System.FinalException: Collection is read-only
Error is in expression '{!addParameter}' in page parameterspage

**Class.ParameterController.addParameter: line 21, column 1**

**2. Pagination Issue**

When click on the next button(onNextR) i'm not able to fetch the other records,

Kindly let me know in case of any further details or clarifications.

Regards,

Arun

Answer (score 2):

1. From the [StandardSetController Class documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm):

   > getRecords: Returns the list of sObjects in the current
   >   page set. **This list is immutable**, i.e. you can't call clear() on it.

   This means you can not add new values to this list.
2. You are rerendering some visualforce element with id `pb` but there is no element with that id.

Comment: Thanks MastOr for your quick reply, 

For 1st issue what is the right solution to followed, how to make muttable.

For 2nd problem I added the id in three areas to render

(i)   <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" id="parameter">
(ii)  <apex:pageblockSection id="paramTb">
(iii)  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!parametersList}" var="parameterItem" id="parameterTable">

Then I renamed pb with above one of the id to render the table. There is no change in the screen when i used paramTb and parameterTable. when i used the id parameter there is change only in the buttons and not in the table data.

Comment: @Arun You can not make the list mutable, you need to create it again (eg. query again with a new filter).

Comment: @Arun And try to use `public PageReference onNextR(){ con.next(); return null; }` instead of `public void onNextR()`

Comment: @Mastor: 
For the first point: i'm not able to understand
For the second point: i changed, but still the same behavior, but i would like to have a clarification, what is the use of having a PageReference and returning a null; and which has the same behavior as void.

Comment: @Arun I've read somewhere that is better to usepagereference instead of void method.

Comment: @Mastor: ok but i'm facing the same issue